# PSR-0 Argument passed

Tags: php, psr-0

```
Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Core\Model\Mapper\PostMapper::save() must be an instance of Core\Model\Mapper\Post, instance of Core\Model\Post given, called in C:\wamp\www\Test\index.php on line 16 and defined in C:\wamp\www\Test\Core\Model\Mapper\PostMapper.php on line 15
```

index.php

```
<?php
require_once 'Core/Library/SplClassLoader.php';

$loader = new SplClassLoader('Core', '');
$loader->register();

use Core\Model\Post,
    Core\Model\Mapper\PostMapper;

$db = false;

$postMapper = new PostMapper($db);

$post = new Post;

$postMapper->save($post);
```

The PostMapper interface and PostMapper does have "Post"

```
<?php
namespace Core\Model\Mapper;

interface PostMapperInterface
{

    public function save(Post $post);
}
```

I can't understand why it is complaining about not being a "Post"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a `Post`, but not the `Post` it is looking for.

You seem to be confused by the namespaces. On one occation, `Post` refers to `Core\Model\Mapper\Post`, but what you pass is of type `Core\Model\Post`.

```
namespace Core\Model\Mapper;

interface PostMapperInterface
{

    public function save(Post $post);
}
```

You first state that you are now inside the namespace `Core\Model\Mapper`, so when you refer to `Post` in the method declaration, `Post` **is relative to that namespace**, which is why it wants an instance of the type `Core\Model\Mapper\Post`.

You need to change your code like this:

```
public function save(\Core\Model\Post $post);
```